# Is there a special term for groups, the only subgroups of which are the trivial group and the group itself?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a special term for groups, the only subgroups of which are the trivial group and the group itself? Obviously, any such group is a trivial group or a cyclic group of prime order.

Comment: And in fact, "cyclic group of prime order" is the usual name for them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  They're abelian [simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group) groups, and yes, you've found them all.